# IBM Cloud Query Structure ruby

Tags: ruby, post, watson

I am having issues understanding how to structure my request to IBM Tone Analyzer service. They do not have a SDK for ruby, so I am just trying to create a http request.

However, I keep getting a 'no credentials supplied' response. I just do not know WHERE these credentials have to be put.

I tried having :

> body: {username:'...', password:'...'}

My credentials do work, I was able to get a response with a curl command.

I tried putting these directly in the query. I am just lost.

EDIT: I am using HTTParty to make my request. Currently I am putting my credentials in every field I can think about, so it looks like

```
response = HTTParty.post(
  URL,
  header: @header,
  data: {
    text: @body,
    username: @user,
    password: @password
  },
  body: {
    text: @body,
    username: @user,
    password: @password
  },
  credentials: {
    text: @body,
    username: @user,
    password: @password
  },
  user: {
    username: @user,
    password: @password
  },
  options: {
    username: @user,
    password: @password
  },
  query: {
    text: @body,
    username: @user,
    password: @password
  })
```

Comment: Can you include more of the code you're using so the nature of the call is more obvious?

Comment: Just edited. As you can see, it should be pretty straight-forward. I just can't find the right way to structure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/tone-analyzer/api/v3/#authentication) it appears these credentials are not supplied via the API body, but instead via [HTTP Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). That means you call it this way:

```
response = HTTParty.post(
  URL,
  header: @header,
  data: {
    text: @body,
  },
  basic_auth: {
    username: @user,
    password: @password
  }
)
```

Comment: I thank you very much, this indeed works. I got so used to API docs that fully describe the request, I never realized I don't fully understand HTTP requests ( I guess ).

Comment: A lot of newer APIs put the authentication in a "sideband" other than the JSON payload. Some argue that makes for cleaner API designs.